# CSS selector or XPath that gets information between two i tags?

Tags: css, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to scrape price information, and the HTML of the website looks like this

```
<span class="def-price" datasku='....'>
   <i>$</i>
   "999"
   <i>.00<i>
</span>
```

I want to get 999. (I don't want the dollar sign or the .00) I currently have

```
product_price_sn = product.css('.def-price i').extract()
```

I know it's wrong but not sure how to fix it. Any idea how to scrape that price information? Thanks!

Comment: Use this xpath `//span[@class="def-price"]/text()`

Comment: If supported, you can also try `normalize-space(//span[@class="def-price"]/text()[2] )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this ***xpath*** `//span[@class="def-price"]/text()`

Make sure  you are using `/text()` and not `//text()`. Otherwise it will return all text nodes inside span tag.

or

This ***css selector*** `.def-price::text`. When using css selector don't use `.def-price ::text`, it will return all text nodes like the `//text()` in xpath.

***Using scrapy response.xpath object***

```py
from scrapy.http import Request, HtmlResponse as Response

content = '''<span class="def-price" datasku='....'>
   <i>$</i>
   "999"
   <i>.00<i>
</span>'''.encode('utf-8')

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62849500'

''' mocking scrapy request object '''
request = Request(url=url)

''' mocking scrapy response object '''
response = Response(url=url, request=request, body=content)

''' using xpath  '''

print(response.xpath('//span[@class="def-price"]/text()').extract())
# outputs ['\n   ', '\n   "999"\n   ']

print(''.join(response.xpath('//span[@class="def-price"]/text()').extract()).strip())
# outputs "99"

''' using css selector '''

print(response.css('.def-price::text').extract())
# outputs ['\n   ', '\n   "999"\n   ']

print(''.join(response.css('.def-price::text').extract()).strip())
# outputs "99"
```

See it in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/QueasyUnrealisticHarddrives)

***Using lxml html parser***

```py
from lxml import html

parser = html.fromstring("""
<span class="def-price" datasku='....'>
   <i>$</i>
   "999"
   <i>.00<i>
</span>
"""
)

print(parser.xpath('//span[@class="def-price"]/text()'))
# outputs ['\n   ', '\n   "999"\n   ']

print(''.join(parser.xpath('//span[@class="def-price"]/text()')).strip())
# outputs "999"
```

See it in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/WanWigglyGenerics)

Comment: I'm not sure where to put join and parser? Right now, I did `product.xpath('//span[@class="def-price"]/text()').strip()` but it's not getting anything. product is defined previously in my code as `response.css('.item-bg')` and it's basically what wraps the product info. Would you mind letting me know?

Comment: @TianheXie `parser.xpath('//span[@class="def-price"]/text()')` returns a list of text nodes, join converts this list into a string.

Answer (score 1):

With BeautifulSoup, you can use CSS selector `.def_price` and then `.find_all(text=True, recursive=0)` to get all immediate text.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<span class="def-price" datasku='....'>
   <i>$</i>
   "999"
   <i>.00<i>
</span>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

print( ''.join(soup.select_one('.def-price').find_all(text=True, recursive=0)).strip() )
```

Prints:

```
"999"
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy implements an extension for that as it isn't standard for CSS selectors. So this should work for you:

```
product_price_sn = product.css('.def-price i::text').extract()
```

Here is what the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#extensions-to-css-selectors) say:

> Per W3C standards, CSS selectors do not support selecting text nodes
> or attribute values. But selecting these is so essential in a web
> scraping context that Scrapy (parsel) implements a couple of
> non-standard pseudo-elements:
>
> to select text nodes, use ::text
>
> to select attribute values, use ::attr(name) where name is the name of the attribute that you want the value of